are optional steps in method claims valid or common?
implicit optional step(s) in a method claim:
identifying at least one of a first score and a second score;

The above step covers three possible implementations or modifications:
Infringers:

identifying only a first score
identifying only a second score
identifying a first score and a second score

explicit optional step in a method claim
optionally, identifying a third score;

This optional step can be reworded to:
identifying at least zero of a third score;

questions:

Is the explicit optional step allowed in a patent claim?
If it is allowed, if a competitor leaves out this explicit optional step, will they nonetheless still infringe?



Is the explicit optional step allowed in a patent claim?

After a very brief search, I can't find much evidence of optional method steps in U.S. patents.
But what is the point of an "optional" step?
If the "optional" step is intended to limit the claim, it cannot be optional.
If the "optional" step is not intended to limit the claim, it should not be in the claim. It can simply be stated in the specification that one can optionally do bar between foo and baz to potentially improve results.
Thus there appears to be very little if any point to having an "optional" method step.
Frequently, things that appear optional to the independent claim are added as dependent claims therefrom.
Note that a machine could optionally do something, perhaps under the control of a program and/or by direction of the user, and that could be a valid and useful claim limitation.

If it is allowed, if a competitor leaves out this explicit optional step, will they nonetheless still infringe?

Remember that once you have a definite claim "that which infringes if later, anticipates if earlier." If the competitor still infringes without the optional step, so too will prior art invalidate the claim even if it makes no mention of the optional step.

But do you agree that this step "identifying at least one of a first score and a second score;" implicitly contains optional steps? And from what I've seen statements like "perform at least one", etc. are really common.

_Bear: I don't think one can decompose "at least one of A, B, C" into the supposedly implicit optional steps. One can say "optionally do A", "optionally do B", and "optionally do C" but where is the guarantee that not all of them will be skipped?
